# How to plot graph or take log of run time data of variables in Lauterbach-Trace32 Debugger

Tags: lauterbach

Is it possible to plot a graph or take log for specific variables in Lauterbach-Trace32 Debugger. If yes, Please help me in this topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the feature you are looking for is the **SNOOPer**.

See the chapter "Variable Logging" in the "Training HLL Debugging" from http://www.lauterbach.com/training.html

E.g. if you want to take a log of the variable ***myvar*** you can do this like that:

```
SNOOPer.RESet     
SNOOPer.SELect Var.RANGE(myvar)
SNOOPer.Mode.Changes ON
SNOOPer.Rate 1000.
SNOOPer.Arm
```

This will periodically read the value of *myvar*.

Ensure that reading memory is enabled while the CPU is running. You can enable this with command `SYStem.MemAccess.CPU` (on most CPU architectures) With ARM Cortex CPUs it's `SYStem.MemAccess.DAP` instead.

To plot the recorded samples use the following command:

```
SNOOPer.DRAW.Var %DEFault myvar /MarkedVector
```

If your CPU and debug tool allows the recording of a data trace (e.g. Cortex-M with µTrace or CombiProbe) you can get much better results by using the data trace.